Scalable AVRO schema for Kafka topic
I have an application in which I am using Kafka with a schema registry to produce messages. I have a topic called "plans" which contains fields like id, name, and type (currently having values A, B, and C), etc. There are different fields that have values only for certain types of plans. For example, I have fields such as 'time' and 'duration' that are only for one type of plan, let's say plan type A. There are other fields that are common for B or C type plans. The current AVRO schema is linear, so if I need to add a new type of plan, let's say D, I would have to add 2 or 3 new fields directly into the schema. This causes the fields to grow horizontally at the consumer end. Is there a way to create a scalable AVRO schema, possibly with nested types.The solution am looking for is a scalable schema pattern which may be a nested record or union type, in which i should be able to add new fields and which is not complex at consumer end to consume also.
`
  {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Plan",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "id", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "description", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
    {"name": "planType", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "specificFieldA1", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
    {"name": "specificFieldA2", "type": ["null", "int"], "default": null},
    {"name": "specificFieldB1", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
    {"name": "specificFieldB2", "type": ["null", "double"], "default": null},
    {"name": "specificFieldC1", "type": ["null", "string"], "default": null},
    {"name": "specificFieldC2", "type": ["null", "boolean"], "default": null}
  ]
}`


Avro is designed to be a dynamic data format, for example the Java API has org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder and org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder exactly for that purpose.
So you could do:
package com.example;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecordBuilder;

public final class PlanType1 {
  private static final Schema SCHEMA =
      SchemaBuilder.builder("com.example")
          .record("Plan")
          .fields()
          .requiredString("id")
          .requiredString("name")
          .optionalString("description")
          .requiredString("planType")
          .requiredString("specificFieldA1")
          .requiredInt("specificFieldA2")
          .endRecord();

  public static GenericRecord encode(
      String id, String name, String specificFieldA1, int specificFieldA2) {
    return new GenericRecordBuilder(SCHEMA)
        .set("id", id)
        .set("name", name)
        .set("planType", "PlanType1")
        .set("specificFieldA1", specificFieldA1)
        .set("specificFieldA2", specificFieldA2)
        .build();
  }

  private PlanType1() {}
}

For plan type 1 and similar for any other plan. Also, having a org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord you can simply get(String key) the interesting fields.
